# ionic SQLite doesn't gets imported in Webstorm?

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, webstorm

I am trying to get in touch with app developing with the ionic framework.

I wanted to set up a Database so I've followed the instructions provided by Ionic (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/#instance-members) but when I import it to the app.module it doesn't work:

[image: it gives me that error]

Can anyone help me with that. I am not that much in to it.

Answer (score 0):

i did it you just have to add SQLite in the providers section.